# Set label text struct array string

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I've TableView and want to set All TableViewCell Labels(5 of them) specific string which is located into my struct's array

I tried for in loop in `TableViewCell` but doesn't seem to work

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
  cell.configure(with: cars[indexPath.section])    //
  return cell
    }
///TableViewCell
    func configure(with cars:Cars){
        for car in cars.carModel{
            lbl.text = cars.carModel[car]     //code crashes here 
        }
///Array
struct Cars {
    let carName:String
    let carModel:[String]
    subscript(index: Int) -> String {
        return carModel[index]
    }
}

let cars:[Cars] = [
    Cars(carName: "Mercedes", carModel: ["S Class","A Class", "B Class"]),
    Cars(carName: "BMW", carModel: ["X5","X6","X7"]),
    Cars(carName: "Ford", carModel: ["Fuison","Focus","Mustang"]),
    Cars(carName: "Toyota", carModel: ["Camry", "Corolla"]),
    Cars(carName: "Hyundai", carModel: ["Elantra"])
]
```

Comment: You can't index an array using a string. It also doesn't make sense to try and assign multiple values to a single label. You will just end up with the last value. Probably what you want is for your table to have a section for each car and then the rows in the be the models.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes of course my mistake, I want rows of labels with my Strings

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the enumerated() function. You tried to subscript a string when you should actually subscript an integer.

```
func configure(with cars: Cars) {
    for (index, car) in cars.carModel.enumerated() {
        lbl.text = cars.carModel[index] 
}
```

but you actually don't even need to do that in this scenario. You can also do:

```
func configure(with cars: Cars) {
    for car in cars.carModel {
        lbl.text = car
}
```

`cars.carModel` is a list of type String, which means `car` is a string. You can use it directly.